# Activity Bringing Me to HomeScreen instead of MainActivity

Tags: android, android-activity, location, homescreen, proximity

My app starts off by calling two services: one to collect to location data and another to run calculations on that data and will start proximity alerts every dozen hours for specific points. My problem is that I am getting the proximity alerts to call up a survey activity once the user enters or exits the areas of interest. The survey comes up, but when I call finish() on the Survey activity, the app exits to the home screen and when I resume the app, I go back to the Survey activity again. 
I am not sure if this is because I am calling many proximity alerts and each of them may have called the Survey activity as I walk around so that I would have a whole bunch of Survey activities, but that wouldn't make sense as to why I am brought to the home screen when it finishes.

This is where I call the proximity alerts.

```
private BroadcastReceiver mLocationUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        proxsiglocList = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("Locations");
        for (int l = 0; l < proxsiglocList.size(); l++) {
            addProximityAlert(proxsiglocList.get(l).getLatitude(),
                    proxsiglocList.get(l).getLongitude());
        }
        proxsiglocList.clear();
    }
};

public void addProximityAlert(double latitude, double longitude) {
    LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT + latitude + longitude);
    intent.putExtra("lat", latitude);
    intent.putExtra("lng", longitude);
    PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            intent, 0);
    locManager.addProximityAlert(latitude, longitude, POINT_RADIUS,
            PROX_ALERT_EXPIRATION, proximityIntent);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROX_ALERT_INTENT + latitude
            + longitude);
    registerReceiver(new ProximityIntentReceiver(), filter);
}
```

This is where I call the Surveys from my ProximityAlerts:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;
    Boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);

    double latitude = intent.getDoubleExtra("lat", -1);
    double longitude = intent.getDoubleExtra("lng", -1);

    if (entering) {
        int id = 0;
        int updated = 0;

        LabelDatabase myDatabase = new LabelDatabase(context);
        myDatabase.open();
        Cursor cursor = myDatabase.getAllRows();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
            if ((cursor.getDouble(1) == latitude)
                    && (cursor.getDouble(2) == longitude)) {
                id = cursor.getInt(0);
                updated = cursor.getInt(4);
                break;
            }
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        if (updated != 1) {
            myDatabase.updateAsked(id);
            Intent surveyIntent = new Intent(context, Survey.class);
            surveyIntent.putExtra("id", id);
            surveyIntent.putExtra("lat", latitude);
            surveyIntent.putExtra("lng", longitude);
            surveyIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(surveyIntent);
        }
        myDatabase.close();

    } else {
        int id = 0;
        int updated = 0;

        LabelDatabase myDatabase = new LabelDatabase(context);
        myDatabase.open();
        Cursor cursor = myDatabase.getAllRows();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
            if ((cursor.getDouble(1) == latitude)
                    && (cursor.getDouble(2) == longitude)) {
                id = cursor.getInt(0);
                updated = cursor.getInt(4);
                break;
            }
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        if (updated != 1) {
            myDatabase.updateAsked(id);
            Intent surveyIntent = new Intent(context, Survey.class);
            surveyIntent.putExtra("id", id);
            surveyIntent.putExtra("lat", latitude);
            surveyIntent.putExtra("lng", longitude);
            surveyIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(surveyIntent);
        }
        myDatabase.close();
    }

}
```

and this is part of my Survey Activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.location_survey);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        id = extras.getInt("id");
        lat = extras.getDouble("lat");
        lng = extras.getDouble("lng");
    }

    // Add in the three spinners
    whereSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> whereAdapter = ArrayAdapter
            .createFromResource(this, R.array.where_array,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    whereAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    whereSpinner.setAdapter(whereAdapter);

    whoSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> whoAdapter = ArrayAdapter
            .createFromResource(this, R.array.who_array,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    whoAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    whoSpinner.setAdapter(whoAdapter);

}

// remove row and proximity alert
public void onNotSigClicked(View v) {
    LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    LabelDatabase myDatabase = new LabelDatabase(getBaseContext());
    myDatabase.open();
    myDatabase.deleterow(id);
    myDatabase.close();

    Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT + lat + lng);
    PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            intent, 0);
    locManager.removeProximityAlert(proximityIntent);
    finish();
}

public void onSaveClicked(View v) {
    // Save profile
    saveProfile();
    finish();
}
```

Once again, I am not sure why my Survey Activity or Activities keep bringing me to the home screen and each time I return, I end up back at the survey activity even though I am calling finish(). This works fine when I only encounter my first survey activity though and when I call finish(), I am brought back to my MainActivity.

Comment: So you want to get back to your main activity every time the SurveyActivity finishes?

Comment: Well, I want to figure out why I keep ending up on the homescreen whenever I call finish() in my Survey activity.

Comment: Well, you where coming from the home screen, right? so that is where the back button takes you. If you want a different behavior start your MainActivty with an in intent in onDestroy() in your survey act.